# Transform a JSON object to another with nested structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
  "id": "jsonid",
  "attributes": {
    "personName": {
      "id": "name1",
      "group": "1.1"
    },
    "age": {
      "id": "age1",
      "group": "1.2.1"
    },
    "height": {
      "id": "height1",
      "group": "1.2.2.1"
    }
  }
}
```

The value of the **group** property denotes the position of that attribute in the hierarchy tree starting from the root until the final node. For example, based on the **group** property of the attribute, it needs to be transformed to:

```
{
  "id": "jsonid",
  "attributes": {
    "group1": {
      "id": "group1",
      "attributes": {
        "group1.1": {
          "id": "group1.1",
          "attributes": {
            "personName": {
              "id": "name1"
            }
          }
        },
        "group1.2": {
          "id": "group1.2",
          "attributes": {
            "group1.2.1": {
              "id": "group1.2.1",
              "attributes": {
                "age": {
                  "id": "age1"
                }
              }
            },
            "group1.2.2": {
              "id": "group1.2.2",
              "attributes": {
                "group1.2.2.1": {
                  "id": "1.2.2.1",
                  "attributes": {
                    "height": {
                      "id": "height1"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have created a function that accepts all the unique group and breaking into possible combinations. For the above JSON object, possible combinations would be : ["1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.2.1", "1.2.2", "1.2.2.1"]. The method would iterate on these values:

```
allPossible.map((groupId, index, array) => {
      createGroups(groupId, index, array);
});
```

and the function -

```
const createGroups = (groupId, index, array) => {
      let groupObject = {
        [groupId]: {
          id: groupId,
          attributes: {},
        },
      };
      if (array[index + 1]) {
        //If next element exists
        if (groupId.length === array[index + 1].length) {
          //To Check if the element should be in the same level 
//e.g. group ids 1.1 and 1.2 should be under group id 1
          let groupIdPrevious = array[index - 1];
          groupObject[groupIdPrevious].attributes = createGroups(
            array[index + 1],
            index + 1,
            array
          );
        }
        groupObject[groupId].attributes = createGroups(
          array[index + 1],
          index + 1,
          array
        );
      }
      return groupObject;
    };
```

Comment: Any idea you've tried that does not work?

Comment: the final structure is convoluted, hard to understand and potentially hard to use with duplicated sematics like IDs and prop names, i would suggest to simplify it first

Comment: @8ns - Added the code logic

Comment: I can see two "errors" in your code: first is that .map methods expects a return statement, so you should either "return createGroups(groupId, index, array);" or remove surrounding "{}"; second the method createGroups tries to access array[index - 1] without checking that index is > 0. Anyway, I suggest you looking for .reduce method instead, I think it will suite better for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the different combinations, the subkeys can be created with something like this :

```js
const data = { "id": "jsonid", "attributes": {
    "personName": { "id": "name1", "group": "1.1" },
    "age": { "id": "age1", "group": "1.2.1" },
    "height": { "id": "height1", "group": "1.2.2.1" } } }

let result = { ...data, attributes: {} }

for (let key in data.attributes)
{
  const value = data.attributes[key]
  let group = 'group' + value.group, attr = result.attributes
  const getAttributes = id => (attr[id] ??= { id, attributes: {} }).attributes
  
  for (let i = group.indexOf('.'); i > 0; i = group.indexOf('.', i + 1))
  {
    attr = getAttributes(group.slice(0, i))
  }
  
  getAttributes(group)[key] = { id: value.id }
}

console.log( result )
```